# Get mouse position on screen (no figure)

Tags: matlab, mouseevent

I'm using a projector to project something on the ground at a certain angle. But to do that whilst maintaining proportions and not let it be distorted by the keystone effect, I need to find a homography matrix.

What I'd like to do is take an object of known size (a sheet of A4 paper) and place it on the ground. Then click on its edges to get their positions on screen, and then calculate what I need.

I thought of using the `get(0,'Pointerlocation')` but do not know how to get its value "on click". Maybe use in combination with `input(prompt)`?

Small clarification, I am not using a figure behind this.

Comment: If you're not using a figure, what are you using? Please see: [mcve].

Comment: You need a window to display the image. This is a figure. If you want to acquire mouse clicks in a window of another application, matlab would be definitely the wrong tool to do this.

Comment: This is like two lines of code in Python. `import pyautogui as pg; x, y = pg.position()`

Comment: The thing is, I'm making a simulink model to measure some data and according to the data, project something on the floor. But for the projection to keep is shape, and not be distorted by the Keystone effect (if I project a square, I get a trapezoid), I need to calculate the homography matrix that would then be applied to what I'm projecting on the floor. To do that, I put a piece of paper on the floor (with know dimensions, and "click" the mouse on the 4 corners and get their positions on the screen. The projector is connected and recognized as a 2nd monitor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there really is no figure and you are trying to get coordinates outside of the Matlab window/figure and perhaps on a separate video app, you could try something like the following.

It basically has a countdown for you to get your mouse anywhere on the screen and it will return the pixel position of your mouse on the montitor.  You don't have to click on anything.  Just make sure you can see the Main Matlab window so you know when to move the mouse.

```
function screenCoord = getCorners()
screenCoord = zeros(4,2);

for ii = 1:4
    fprintf('Move cursor to Position %d: \n',ii)
    countDown()
    screenCoord(ii,:) = get(0,'PointerLocation');
end

function countDown()
fprintf('Capturing in: ');
for i = 5:-1:1
    fprintf('%d..',i);pause(1)
end
fprintf('0..\n')
```

Output:

```
>> screenCoords = getCorners
Move cursor to Position 1: 
Capturing in: 5..4..3..2..1..0..
Move cursor to Position 2: 
Capturing in: 5..4..3..2..1..0..
Move cursor to Position 3: 
Capturing in: 5..4..3..2..1..0..
Move cursor to Position 4: 
Capturing in: 5..4..3..2..1..0..

screenCoords =

   113   922
   943   904
   976   356
   323   376
```

EDIT: 
An alternative to the countdown would be to use the input function as long as you can keep the Main Matlab window as the focus.  Just replace the call to `countDown()` with

```
input('Press Enter when ready.');
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going for something like that (keyboard input for timing of the recording of the mouse position), but was hoping that I'm missing an obvious way to do in for clicking the mouse :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in matlab to solve this task is using a figure.

I would create a full screen blank figure:

```
figure('position', get(0,'screensize'))
```

Then use `ginput()` function to record a sequence of mouse click positions:

```
[x,y,buttons] = ginput(4)
```

This will record the 4 corner points of your sheet of paper clicked when you position the mouse on the projected image to the corners of your "paper". The `buttons` array tells you which mouse button was clicked. The `x` and `y` arrays keep the position in the current axis coordinate system. The result could look like this:

```
x =

   0.20783
   0.79309
   0.78157
   0.15484

y =

   0.72422
   0.71539
   0.27109
   0.22106

buttons =

   1
   1
   1
   1
```

From this coordinates you can calculate your distortion function.

See [help of `ginput()`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) for more options.

Comment: ginput implicitly creates a figure and an axes object by calling `gca` function.

Comment: How does creation of an empty `axes` object help?

Comment: It has a coordinate range of [0,1] for both axis and allows ginput to define the mouse coordinates. For the above question I assumed that an axis object already exists, otherwise there is nothing to click into.

Comment: I don't need you to quote the documentation to me. Why would you assume that if the question explicitly states it isn't present?

Comment: When answering the question I was not aware of the meaning of "(no figure)".

Comment: The suggestion is also good. I am thinking of making a figure, but not a blank one, but with horizontal and vertical lines (10 each) just to illustrate the distortion. Will try it out :) Tnx!